# debian broadcom wireless dropping out

Tags: debian, wifi, broadcom

Sometimes my wifi just disconnects for no reason what so ever.

I caught this log in dmesg.

```
[54591.176796] CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3457)
[54591.176797] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3457)
[54591.176799] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3602)
[54591.176800] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3602)
[54591.176801] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3602)
[54591.176803] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3602)
[54591.176804] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3602)
[54591.176806] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3602)
[54591.176806] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3602)
[54591.176816] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3602)
[54591.177788] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[54591.177789] CPU7: Core temperature/speed normal
[54591.177790] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[54591.177792] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[54591.177793] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[54591.177794] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[54591.177796] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[54591.177796] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[54591.177797] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[54591.177802] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[55372.989421] CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4403)
[55372.989422] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4403)
[55372.989424] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4742)
[55372.989425] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4742)
[55372.989426] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4742)
[55372.989427] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4742)
[55372.989430] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4742)
[55372.989432] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4742)
[55372.989433] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4742)
[55372.989439] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4742)
[55372.990403] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[55372.990404] CPU7: Core temperature/speed normal
[55372.990405] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[55372.990416] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[55372.990417] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[55372.990419] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[55372.990420] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[55372.990422] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[55372.990424] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[55372.990426] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[56252.720308] nautilus[18214]: segfault at 80 ip 000000000044baa0 sp 00007ffda5504eb0 error 4 in nautilus[400000+14a000]
[60984.992463] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[60987.262948] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[60987.264999] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[60987.265001] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[60987.265002] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[60987.265004] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60987.265005] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60987.265006] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60987.265007] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60987.265008] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[60987.265009] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[60987.265010] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60987.265011] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[60995.985792] wl0: link down (wlan0)
[60995.985920] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[60995.988168] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[60995.988170] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[60995.988171] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[60995.988173] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60995.988174] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60995.988175] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60995.988176] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60995.988177] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[60995.988178] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[60995.988179] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[60995.988179] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[61065.950297] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[61167.759367] wl0: link down (wlan0)
[61167.778323] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[61167.780202] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[61167.780205] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[61167.780207] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[61167.780209] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61167.780211] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61167.780212] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61167.780214] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61167.780216] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[61167.780218] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[61167.780219] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61167.780221] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[61181.811998] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[61181.814645] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[61181.814648] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[61181.814650] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[61181.814652] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61181.814653] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61181.814654] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61181.814656] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61181.814657] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[61181.814658] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[61181.814659] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61181.814661] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[61181.844400] wl0: online cpus 1
[61181.844886] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
[61192.368420] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[61202.262999] wl0: link down (wlan0)
[61202.263163] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[61202.265355] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[61202.265356] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[61202.265358] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[61202.265359] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61202.265360] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61202.265361] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61202.265362] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61202.265363] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[61202.265364] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[61202.265365] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[61202.265366] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[61212.609292] wl0: link up (wlan0)
```

you see there's a segfault here

```
[56252.720308] nautilus[18214]: segfault at 80 ip 000000000044baa0 sp 00007ffda5504eb0 error 4 in nautilus[400000+14a000]
```

then things goes sideways.

Is there any sane way to debug this?